# SwiftUI Catalyst App in macOS computer - Which path should I use to save an image in my Mac local disk?

Tags: save, swiftui, catalyst

I have this simply code, that I run with Catalyst in macOS:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var pathURL = "/Users/cesare/Desktop/Test"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("/Users/cesare/Desktop/Test", text: $pathURL)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
            Button(action: {
                let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: self.pathURL, isDirectory: true)

                let nameImage = "ImageTest" + ".jpg"
                let fileUrlWithName = fileUrl.appendingPathComponent(nameImage)

                let imageData = UIImage(named: "2020-03-05_11-19-22_5")?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
                do {
                    try imageData!.write(to: fileUrlWithName)
                } catch {
                    print("** saveImageData error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }) {
                Text("Save Image")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `Assets.xcassets` I put `2020-03-05_11-19-22_5` image. When I press `Save Image` button, I have this error: `You don’t have permission to save the file “ImageTest.jpg” in the folder “Test”.`
Why I don't have permission for save image in my Desktop?
I tried to export the app contained in Products, without getting any results.
Which path should I use to save an image in my Mac local disk?

Answer (score 4):

To save the document in any folder, you need to set the `App Sandbox` to `NO`.
[image]