# SwiftUI Saving Image to macOS Catalyst

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14

I am trying to save images on a macOS Catalyst app using the below code. It was adopted from [SwiftUI Catalyst App in macOS computer - Which path should I use to save an image in my Mac local disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030993/swiftui-catalyst-app-in-macos-computer-which-path-should-i-use-to-save-an-imag)

However I get the error `"The file "abstract-1.jpg" doesn't exist."`

I have the image **abstract-1** in my **Assets.xcassets** folder, so I'm not sure why it's not seeing it for this save operation? I've also tried just using `item.name` without appending the **.jpg** but it produces the same error. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
Button(action: {
                                        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: self.pathURL, isDirectory: true)
                                        let nameImage = item.name + ".jpg"
                                        let fileURLwithName = fileURL.appendingPathComponent(nameImage)
                                        let imageData = UIImage(named: item.name)?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
                                        do {
                                            try imageData!.write(to: fileURLwithName)
                                        } catch {
                                            print("** saveImageData error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                        }
                                    }) {
                                            Label("Save to Pictures Directory", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.down")
                                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to do two things:

1. NOT use something like `~/Pictures` in my **pathURL**. This needed to be explicitly declared like `@State private var pathURL = "/Users/jimbob/Desktop/"`
2. Change App Sandbox to NO in appname.entitlements

Now to try and get either the user's home directory path, or get a 'save location' dialogue to pop up.